# Replace multiple placeholders with string.Empty

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a string with placeholders.

```
string Str="<tr><td>This is the {{data}} with {{sample}} string which needs to be {{handled}}</td></tr>";
```

I'm getting data from database and will replace strings according to data i get from the same.

After that,there may be non replaced strings.e.g.

```
string Str="<tr><td>This is the replaced data with {{sample}} string which needs to be {{handled}}</td></tr>";
```

Now,i wanted to remove all the `<tr>` if it contains data with {{...}}. In above example,{{sample}} and {{handled}} can be removed along with whole row(`<tr>`). How to implement that?

Comment: are sample and handled const strings? can you highlight what you want to replace with difference color(suggest attach picture from word)

Comment: how you replacing the {{data}} with the actual data? string.format("{0},{1}","Hello", "World") ??

Comment: Split the text on `<tr>`, chuck out whatever you don't want (as per Natrium suggestion for example), assemble it back ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to do that in a safer way:

```
var cleanedString = Regex.Replace(yourString, "<tr>.*{{[^}]*}}.*?</tr>", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCas);
```

This regular expression works with a string containing more than one `<tr>`, so basically the string

```
<tr><td>This is the replaced data with {{sample}} string which needs to be {{handled}}</td></tr><tr><td>Another row</td></tr>
```

becomes

```
<tr><td>Another content</td></tr>
```

However this won't work with nested tables, e.g.

```
<tr><td>{{foo}}<table><tr><td>bar</td></tr></table></td></tr>
```

would become

```
</table></td></tr>.
```

If you need to support that I suspect you really need to be properly parsing the whole DOM, though you could certainly change the reg-ex to simply skip over TR's that have nested tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Str.Contains("{{"))
{
    Str = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: This will not work as i am having whole html as string. I wanted to replace only the row which contains such place holders.

Comment: @user2645738 you did not specify that.